# Else if statement and add day function

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email-notification

Here is some sort of e-mail reminder workflow.

The task is to create a workflow, that will send reminder 1 day before shift day, but the thing is to receive Monday shift notification on Friday(and not on Sunday), So I added a trigger(flag), every Monday will have that trigger and will send reminder 3 days before.

The question is, why workflow works with out "add day" function (it sends email at the moment, when the event was created), and when I add "add day" function, it gets terminated.

And I don't know why.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "terminated"? Also, by -3 days will you get a "pasted date"?

Comment: Sorry, i meant suspended,but if i press "resume this workflow " nothing happens. Adding -3 days i will get "today",if today is "friday"and "start date"is on monday,

Comment: Is it works if you minus 2 instead of minus 3?  Please test.  Also could you check the uls log to see any error occur at the moment of suspended?

Comment: even with -2, it still suspends with this massage             An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: value at System.DateTime.AddTicks(Int64 value) at Microsoft.Activities.Expressions.AddToDate.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)

Comment: at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)